# Failed to initialize StartAppAd

Tags: java, android, eclipse, startapp

im trying to integrate startapp in my app, followed the instruction manual found error in step3 which was Initialize startapp.

Step 1: Add the SDK JAR to your Eclipse project - OK

Step 2: Update your manifest file - OK

Step 3: Initialize StartApp Ad
In the OnCreate method of your activity, call the static function:
StartAppAd.init(this, "", "");

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StartAppAd.init(this, "xxx", "xxx"); <--------[X] CANNOT BE RESOLVED
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
```

Is there anything wrong? seems like my activity cannot link to the jar.
The jar filename is StartAppInApp-2.1.3.jar

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the startapp package

```
import com.startapp.android.publish.StartAppAd;
```